# Loading HTML content containing inline script via jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, scripting

### The Background

- I run an ASP.NET site using Graffiti CMS for a local charitable/service organization.
- The leaders of the organization want to start integrating a third-party back-end management system that exposes content as full HTML pages.
- One of the pages, the officer list, uses inline script to load pictures or placeholders (depending on whether or not there is a picture for the given officer).
- I've created a server-side proxy that enables loading the content from these pages using jQuery's `.load()` AJAX function.
- I can display this content fine using an iframe, but that feels really kludgy, and if the size of the content changes, I may need to alter the size of the iframe to ensure it all displays (blech!).

### The Problem

If I create a `<div>` in a Graffiti post, and use `$("#divid").load(url)` to load the content, the HTML content loads fine, but the inline script is stripped out, so neither the officer images nor the placeholders are displayed.

### The Question

Understanding that the reason for the problem is that jQuery is almost certainly trying to protect against potentially bad stuff by removing the inline script before I load it into my DOM, is there a way using jQuery to grab this HTML and load it into my DOM that will preserve the script, but not open major security holes? I do trust the system from which I'm loading the content, if that makes a difference.

Suggestions? I'm looking to keep this as simple as possible...anything too complex, and I'm just as well off to stick with the iframe.

Thanks in advance!

[@devhammer](http://twitter.com/devhammer)

Comment: Is the page you're trying to load from on the same domain name?

Comment: by inline script to you mean `script` tags or onclick=someScript?

Comment: No, the page is in a different domain, but I set up a server-side proxy on my domain to pull the content over.

Comment: Inline like so:
`<script> if ('' == '') { document.write('<img src="/path/member-small.jpg">'); } else { document.write('<img src="/otherpath/" width=80>'); } </script>`

Comment: The scripts appear right in the middle of the markup.

Comment: I've used JQuery to load html pages with inline script many times before, what you're talking about _should_ work, but you should probably be checking for javascript errors when it loads, otherwise nothing may happen.

Comment: This is not jQuery's fault here, once the document is loaded, you can't `document.write` anymore.. so you must create/insert nodes in the DOM instead of writing into the document. If you don't have control over that, I'm affraid you'll have to go with iframes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't work for me...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var dynamic = 'begin <script type="text/javascript">alert("hello");<\/script> end';
                $('#test').html(dynamic);
            });
        </script>
        <div id="test"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The alert box is showing.. but if you replace it with a `document.write`, nothing in the document.write appears... you have "begin end"

Hope this helps!

Comment: Right...makes sense. The scripts are there, but `document.write` won't work because it's too late to call that.

Comment: Yes "The document.write command must be carried out during the loading of the page." -http://java-programming.suite101.com/article.cfm/javascript_documentwrite_tutorial

You can mark your post as answered :)

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue when you use document.write.  If you have the ability to modify the source pages you can modify them to use the innerHtml technique instead.

To do so you would change something like this:

```
<div id="testDiv">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<img src='image1.jpg' alt='' />");
  </script>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div id="testDiv">
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementByid('testDiv').innerHTML = "<img src='image1.jpg' alt='' />";
</script>
```

Comment: I can ask the guy who runs the system where these pages reside if he can modify the page, but given that there are a number of other folks using the same system, I would be surprised if he'd be open to that. Prime example of some of the perils of reusing a system that wasn't designed for reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the HTML manually, like this:

```
$.get(url, function(htmlText) { $('#divid').html(htmlText); });
```

I'm pretty sure this will execute the scripts.

Comment: Be careful, there are things a page-load-time script may expect to be able to do that you can't do once the page has loaded. Primarily: anything that calls `document.write` to add content to the page as it loads will completely destroy your existing page.

Comment: Funny you should mention `document.write` since that's precisely what these scripts are doing.

I did try `$.get`, and could get the content (and scripts) to load, but the scripts would not execute.

Comment: when the HTML is loaded in this way, how do you use the jQuery to grab the part of HTML you want? the .load removes [html][body] etc. but now  this would need to be done manually... any ideas?

Comment: @BerggreenDK: `$('someSelector', htmlText).html()`.

Comment: @SLaks: Ehm, yes - I could have been more specific. But I was refering to the question of how we get the inline scripts and then execute the scripts within the HTML?