# how to show HTML tags in DIV

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML static page how i can show it in a div ?

Comment: Would you like to display additional content within some DIV element or actually display tags (ie. actually displaying a tag like `<span>Some span</span>`)?

Comment: Meet your new best friend: api.jquery.com.

Answer (score 1):

If you can include [jQuery](http://jquery.com), then the task will be very simple.

```
$("#your-div-id").load("static.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [this previous question on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659202/loading-html-content-containing-inline-script-via-jquery)

Alternatively, [frinity has an easy tutorial](http://frinity.blogspot.com/2008/06/load-remote-content-into-div-element.html) on how to do this.